# How to build the MYSQL query out of the tables given below?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables which having master child relationship.

Master table:

```
master Id | Name 
  1       | name1
  2       | Name2
```

Child Table:

```
ChildId| MasterId | Detail |
  1    |  1       | det01  |
  2    |  1       | det02  |
  3    |  2       | det03  |
  4    |  2       | det04  |  
  5    |  2       | det05  |
```

What I want:

```
ChildId| MasterId | Detail |
  5    |  2       | det05  |
  2    |  1       | det02  |
```

this table is ordered by ChildId desc but having a single record against a MasterId. please let me know how to achieve this target.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `group by` with aggregate function `max()`

```
select  c.masterid, max(c.childid), max(c.detail)
from child c inner join master m on c.masterid=m.`master id`
group by c.masterid
order by c.masterid desc
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5862/2)

Answer (score 0):

It might be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT MAX(child.ID) as ChildID, master.ID as MasterID, MAX(child.Detail) as Detail
FROM child 
INNER JOIN master 
ON child.MasterID = master.ID
GROUP BY master.ID
ORDER BY child.ID DESC;
```

The output would be in this case:

```
ChildID MasterID Detail
5       2        det05
2       1        det02
```

I could correct it with proper field and table names if you kindly provide me with them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(C.ChildID) as ChildID,C.MasterID,C.Detail
FROM Child C,Master M
WHERE M.master_Id=C.MasterID
GROUP BY C.MasterID
ORDER BY C.MasterID DESC
```

Result:

```
CHILDID MASTERID    DETAIL
5        2          det03
2        1          det01
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5b59/7).